# How to set up TextSwitcher for a countdown timer

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a countdown that animates the time ticking as a vertical slide as it changes. I've tried using textswitcher, but haven't been able to get an instance working for my scenario

These are the text views inside my XML that each change

```
<TextView
           android:id="@+id/timerDays"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="133dp"
           android:layout_marginBottom="130dp"
           android:text="days"
           android:textSize="20sp"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/scrollView3"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/timerHour"
           app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/timerMins"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="mins"
           android:textSize="20sp"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/timerSecs"
           app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/timerHour"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/timerDays" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/timerSecs"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
           android:text="secs"
           android:textSize="20sp"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/timerMins"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/timerMins" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/timerHour"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="hour"
           android:textSize="20sp"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/timerMins"
           app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/timerDays"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/timerDays" />
```

And this is the java code that is changing each text view accordingly. This is currently functioning as intended

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(tripsViewModel.class);

        loadContainer1 = (ConstraintLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.loadContainer);

        //setContentView(R.layout.fragment_trips);

        //TextSwitcher my_text_switcher;

        TextView tv_countdownDays;
        tv_countdownDays = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timerDays);
        TextView tv_countdownHour;
        tv_countdownHour = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timerHour);
        TextView tv_countdownMins;
        tv_countdownMins = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timerMins);
        TextView tv_countdownSecs;
        tv_countdownSecs = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timerSecs);


        Calendar start_calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar end_calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        end_calendar.set(2021, 2, 5); // 10 = November, month start at 0 = January


        long start_millis = start_calendar.getTimeInMillis(); //get the start time in milliseconds
        long end_millis = end_calendar.getTimeInMillis(); //get the end time in milliseconds
        long total_millis = (end_millis - start_millis); //total time in milliseconds
        //end_calendar.set(2021, 7, 12); // 10 = November, month start at 0 = January

        //1000 = 1 second interval
        CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(total_millis, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                long days = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(millisUntilFinished);
                millisUntilFinished -= TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(days);

                long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished);
                millisUntilFinished -= TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hours);

                long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished);
                millisUntilFinished -= TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(minutes);

                long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished);
                tv_countdownDays.setText(days + ""); //You can compute the millisUntilFinished on hours/minutes/seconds
                tv_countdownHour.setText(hours + "");
                tv_countdownMins.setText(minutes + "");
                tv_countdownSecs.setText(seconds + "");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                tv_countdownSecs.setText("Finished!");
            }
        };
        cdt.start();

    }
```